Widget doesn't fit in the center and divider not showing
I am trying to the profile of a client but there is something messed up in the code because the second widget it's not in the center and the divider it's not showing under the name and button. Here it's the code
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flashy_tab_bar2/flashy_tab_bar2.dart';
import 'workout_post_detail.dart';
import 'editprofile_business.dart';
import 'seeall_workout.dart';

class ClientPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ClientPageState createState() => _ClientPageState();
}

class _ClientPageState extends State<ClientPage> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Your profile',
              style:
                  TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white)),
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        ),
        body: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Stack(alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, children: [
              Column(children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                Center(
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 60,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                        child: CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 46,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade100,
                            child: Text('Pic')))),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                Text(
                  'Usermane',
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 60,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.90,
                  decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                      shape: const StadiumBorder(),
                      color: Colors.grey[200],
                      shadows: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                          blurRadius: 10,
                          spreadRadius: 2,
                        ),
                      ]),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.0, right: 25),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'Subscribers',
                          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          '8',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.grey),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Text(
                  'PROGRAMS SUBSCRIBED',
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Stack(children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 300,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.90,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      // shape: const StadiumBorder(),
                      color: Colors.white,
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                          spreadRadius: 5,
                          blurRadius: 7,
                          offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  _userprofile(context)
                ]),
              ])
            ])));
  }
}

_userprofile(context) {
  return Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
    child: Row(
      children: [
        CircleAvatar(
            radius: 35,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            child: CircleAvatar(
                radius: 46,
                backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade100,
                child: Text('Pic'))),
        SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
        Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
              child: Text(
                'username',
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
              child: Text('Name of the program'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 20,
        ),
        Column(children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          ),
          Container(
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text(
                'ACCESS',
                style:
                    TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),
              ),
              style: ButtonStyle(
                backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.black),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Divider(
            height: 10,
            color: Colors.black,
          )
        ])
      ],
    ),
  );
}

This is the outcome
How I can be secure that the button ACCESS it's staying on the right side and the divider is showing up under the button and text and avatar

try this:
I put all the explanations, where you need to make changes inside the code as comments
class ClientPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ClientPage({super.key});

  @override
  ClientPageState createState() => ClientPageState();
}

class ClientPageState extends State<ClientPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(
          'Your profile',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          children: [
            Column(
              children: [
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                Center(
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 60,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 46,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade100,
                      child: const Text('Pic'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                const Text(
                  'Usermane',
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 60,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.90,
                  decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                      shape: const StadiumBorder(),
                      color: Colors.grey[200],
                      shadows: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                          blurRadius: 10,
                          spreadRadius: 2,
                        ),
                      ]),
                  child: const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.0, right: 25),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'Subscribers',
                          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          '8',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.grey,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                const Text(
                  'PROGRAMS SUBSCRIBED',
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Stack(
                  children: [
                    //align your container to center here with Align widget
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Container(
                        height: 300,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.90,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          // shape: const StadiumBorder(),
                          color: Colors.white,
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                              color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                              spreadRadius: 5,
                              blurRadius: 7,
                              offset: const Offset(
                                  0, 3), // changes position of shadow
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    _userprofile(context)
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

_userprofile(context) {
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 10, 16, 10),
    //wrap the Row in a Column and take out the Divider out of Row,
    // and put it inside the Column right below the Row
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            CircleAvatar(
                radius: 35,
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                child: CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 30,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade100,
                    child: const Text('Pic'))),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            const Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'username',
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                  child: Text('Name of the program'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              width: 20,
            ),
            const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              style: ButtonStyle(
                backgroundColor: WidgetStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.black),
              ),
              child: const Text(
                'ACCESS',
                style:
                    TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        const Divider(
          thickness: 1,
          color: Colors.black,
        )
      ],
    ),
  );
}

and here is the result:


https://imgur.com/a/TBDb0C1 it still doesn't center the second widget correctly , it's going somewhere to the left... and also the divider goes out

I resolved, I had to clean the project , it's also an issue , when I duplicate _userprofile(context) to see how it looks if there appears more users nothing shows, just the first one , why?

It seems that you are over using the Stack() widget. To completely make sure the "Access" button and the widgets stay on their respective sides despite changes in text sizes you need to define how the row should align its children and you can combine the avatar and the column as a grouped widget using another row as below:
_userprofile(context) {
  return Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
    child: Row(//<<<====parent row
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,////<<<<<<<======Here you can change it to what you prefer
      children: [
        Row(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
           children:[
CircleAvatar(
            radius: 35,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            child: CircleAvatar(
                radius: 46,
                backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade100,
                child: Text('Pic'))),
        SizedBox(
         width : 10,<<===play with the width size you want
        ),
        Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
              child: Text(
                'username',
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
              child: Text('Name of the program'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
           ],
        ),
        //SizedBox(
          //width: 20,
        //),
        Column(children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          ),
          Container(
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text(
                'ACCESS',
                style:
                    TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),
              ),
              style: ButtonStyle(
                backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.black),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 10,
            width: 40,//your desired width
            color: Colors.black,
          )
        ])
      ],
    ),
  );
}

I advice you to use custom divider using container at least you visually know what you are working with.
And to make the widget get centered just remove the stack. Wrap the container with padding and let the size of the background container be that of the users screen.
Padding(
padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0)//<<<<==Use padding size you like
   child: Container(
                    height: 300,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      // shape: const StadiumBorder(),
                      color: Colors.white,
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                          spreadRadius: 5,
                          blurRadius: 7,
                          offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
)


To make sure that the access button always stays on the right, you can wrap the access button in an expanded and aligned widget and use a column to add a divider at the bottom.
_userprofile(context) {
  return Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
    child: Column(
      
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
             
            CircleAvatar(
                radius: 35,
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                child: CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 46,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade100,
                    child: Text('Pic'))),
            SizedBox(width: 20),
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'username',
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                  child: Text('Name of the program'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text(
                      'ACCESS',
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                      backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.black),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Divider(
          height: 2,
          color: Colors.black,
        )
      ],
    ),
  );
}


imgur.com/a/TBDb0C1 it still doesn't center the second widget correctly , it's going somewhere to the left... and also the divider goes out
